# Read text file with the same delimiter at the end

Tags: java

I have 2 problems with my loadTxt method.

1- I get the path as a `file[].toString` type from another method and the path look like this:

```
C:\files\texts\text1.txt
```

But I need the path with 2 backsplashes for `nio.file.Path` like this:

```
C:\\files\\texts\\text1.txt
```

2 - The second problem is with the loadtxt method. I think this is because of the same delimiter ";" at the end the text file I get a `java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1` .

```
public void loadTxt(String path)
{
    Path pathToFile = Paths.get("z:\\Filiallager_21_Regal_1.txt");
    try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile,
            StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)) {
        
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            String[] attributes = line.split(";");            
            line = br.readLine();    
        }
        
    }
    
    catch (IOException ioe) 
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My texts data look like this:

```
1;5;emitter;
2;7;jim;
3;2;ert;
```

Comment: The comma at the end is not causing the exception assuming that all you are doing is printing the first of the array, but it is usually safer the test against the length of the array before printing out an index e.g. a blank line with no comma will have no elements.

Comment: You're right. When I have only 4 rows there is no problem. But how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When splitting using a delimiter it is best to test against the length of the array to ensure that you do not exceed its bounds:

```
String line = br.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    String[] attributes = line.split(";");   
    if (attributes.length > 3) {
        System.out.println (attributes[3]);
    }     
    line = br.readLine();    
}
```

or you could use a loop

```
for (int x = 0; x < attributes.length; x++)
{
    System.out.println (attributes[x]);
}
```

**edit**

As per the error reading your file, I think you are better off using a `FileReader`

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.txt"));
```

Comment: The problem is with the txt file. Because it is too big for a string type. I should replace `String line = br.readLine();` with something else

Comment: I removed the syso.

Answer (score -1):

For Problem 1:
You can replace slash with double slash using `path = path.replace("\\", "\\\\");`

For Problem 2:

I really did not get what is the issue, I tried with your code and sample data and it is working fine for me. Either provide exception details or if the data you provided is correct or not.

Comment: The problem is with the txt file. Because it is too big for a string type. I should replace String line with something else.